# Click on the form button doesnt work with an open keyboard

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ios7, twitter-bootstrap-3

The form button "comment" isn't working. Clicks are useless with an open keyboard.
Does anyone know why is this happening? The form is inside a modal bootstrap3.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Message', 'send']);return Message.send(this);" id="messageForm">
  <input type="hidden" value="25" id="conversation_id" name="conversation_id">
  <input type="hidden" value="2014-04-08 08:04:50" id="last_message_date" name="last_message_date">
  <div id="messages_feedback_Div"></div><!-- id="messages_feedback_Div" -->
  <fieldset>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label for="message_body" class="control-label">Nuevo mensaje</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea placeholder="Introduce aquí tu comentario" class="form-control" rows="2" id="message_body" name="message_body" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <button value="Send" name="_message_send" class="btn" type="submit">Comentar</button>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `.control-group` and `.controls` no longer exist in Bootstrap 3...